# How can I run NUnit tests in parallel?

Tags: nunit

I've got a large acceptance test (~10 seconds per test) test suite written using NUnit. I would like to make use of the fact that my machines are all multiple core boxes. Ideally, I'd be able to have one test running per core, independently of other tests.

There is PNUnit, but it's designed for testing for threading synchronization issues and things like that, and I didn't see an obvious way to accomplish this.

Is there a switch/tool/option I can use to run the tests in parallel?

Comment: Even I would like to know more about this. @Billy ONeal please post an answer if you find one.

Comment: You say ten seconds per test and ideally one test running per core. Are the tests that CPU intensive? Otherwise it should be possible to have many more running concurrently.

Comment: @Mattias: Yes, the tests are CPU intensive.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you want to run NUnit tests in parallel, there are at least 2 options:

- NCrunch offers it out of the box (without changing anything, but is a commercial product)
- NUnit 3 offers a [Parallelizable](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/parallelizable.html) attribute, which can be used to denote which tests can be run in parallel

Comment: This answer seems wrong given the question, more a good suggestion than true answer.  To my mind NCrunch needs your upvotes and should be the top answer as it can can run (NUnit) tests concurrently within the same or multiple processes and across one or many machines and will do so from VS or from a build server.

Comment: @chillitom NCrunch was released after this question was answered, and is a good choice (as this should just work out of the box, although it's overly pricey for some). Other options in the future may include NUnit 3, which may offer parallel running of tests (according to https://github.com/nunit/dev/wiki/Roadmap).

Comment: Although this is the top answer, it's no longer as correct as it once was. Nunit 3.0 was released at the tail end of 2015 which now has a Parallelizable attribute. Ref: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Parallelizable-Attribute

Answer (score 39):

NUnit version 3 will support running tests in parallel:

Adding the attribute to a class: `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)]` will run your tests in parallel.

> • ParallelScope.None  indicates that the test may not be run in parallel
>   with other tests.
>
> •  ParallelScope.Self  indicates that the test
>   itself may be run in parallel with other tests.
>
> • ParallelScope.Children  indicates that the descendants of the test may
>   be run in parallel with respect to one another.
>
> • ParallelScope.Fixtures  indicates that fixtures may be run in parallel
>   with one another.

[NUnit Framework-Parallel-Test-Execution](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallelizable-Attribute)

Answer (score 10):

If your project contains multiple test DLLs you can run them in parallel using this MSBuild script.  Obviously you'll need to tweak the paths to suit your project layout.

To run with 8 cores run with: `c:\proj> msbuild /m:8 RunTests.xml`

**RunTests.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="RunTestsInParallel" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
    <Nunit Condition=" '$(Nunit)' == '' ">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\tools\nunit-console-x86.exe</Nunit>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- see http://mikefourie.wordpress.com/2010/12/04/running-targets-in-parallel-in-msbuild/ -->

  <Target Name="RunTestsInParallel">
    <ItemGroup> 
      <TestDlls Include="..\bin\Tests\$(Configuration)\*.Tests.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup> 
      <TempProjects Include="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" > 
        <Properties>TestDllFile=%(TestDlls.FullPath)</Properties> 
      </TempProjects> 
    </ItemGroup> 

    <MSBuild Projects="@(TempProjects)" BuildInParallel="true" Targets="RunOneTestDll" /> 
  </Target>

  <Target Name="RunOneTestDll"> 
    <Message Text="$(TestDllFile)" />
    <Exec Command="$(Nunit) /exclude=Integration $(TestDllFile)  /labels /xml:$(TestDllFile).results.xml"
      WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\bin\Tests\$(Configuration)" /> 
  </Target>

</Project>
```

**Update**
If I were answering this question now I would highly recommend *NCrunch* and its command line test running tool for maximum test run performance.  There's nothing like it and it'll revolutionise your code-test-debug cycle at the same time.

Comment: This helped me to reduce unit tests run time from 3 min to 2 min. I've tested on a 2-core CPU.

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to adding the Parallelizable attribute to every test class:

Add this into the test project AssemblyInfo.cs class for nunit3 or greater:

```
// Make all tests in the test assembly run in parallel
[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
```

Comment: I had to use `[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]`

Comment: The correct answer is actually

```[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.ContextMask)]``` in AssemblyInfo.cs



ContextMask is not documented, but if you open up the Enum, you will discover that 
```ContextMask = (ParallelScope.Fixtures | ParallelScope.Children)```

Which means every single test that exists in this assembly will be considered parallelizable, unless you set a different value for a specific class, method, or test.

Answer (score 4):

In [this article](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/nunit-discuss@googlegroups.com/2010-07/msg00095.html) it is mentioned that in order to speed up tests the poster runs multiple instances of NUnit with command parameters specifying which tests each instance should run.

FTA:

> I  ran into an odd problem.
>
> We use nunit-console to run test on
>   our continuous integration server. 
>   Recently we were moving from Nunit
>   2.4.8 to 2.5.5 and from .Net 3.5 to 4.0. To speed up test execution we run multiple instances of Nunit in
>   parallel  with different command line
>   arguments
>
> - We have two copies of our test assemblies and the nunit binaries in 
>     folder A and B.
> - In folder A we execute
>
> nunit-console-x86.exe Model.dll
>   Test.dll /exclude:MyCategory 
>   /xml=TestResults.xml
>   /framework=net-4.0 /noshadow
>
> - In folder B we execute
>
> nunit-console-x86.exe Model.dll
>   Test.dll /include:MyCategory 
>   /xml=TestResults.xml
>   /framework=net-4.0 /noshadow
>
> If we execute the commands in sequence
>   both run successfully. But if we 
>   execute them in parallel only one
>   succeeds. As far as I can tell it's
>   the  one that first loads the test
>   fixtures. The other fails with the
>   message  "Unable to locate fixture".
>
> Is this problem already known? I could
>   not find anything related in the bug 
>   list on launchpad. BTW Our server runs
>   Windows Server 2008 64-bit. I could
>   also reproduce the  problem on Windows
>   7 64-bit.

Assuming this bug is fixed or you are not running the newer version(s) of the software mentioned you should be able to replicate their technique.

**Update**

[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) looks like a tool you can use to automatically run NUnit tests.  They have an NUnit launcher [discussed here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD4/TeamCity+NUnit+Test+Launcher) that could be used to launch multiple NUnit instances.  [Here](http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/07/using-teamcitys-nunit-support-while-keeping-the-output-around/) is a blog post discussing the mergind of multiple NUnit XML results into a single result file.

So theoretically you could have TeamCity automatically launch multiple NUnit tests based on however you want to split up the workload and then merge the results into a single file for post test processing.

Is that automated enough for your needs?

Comment: This is the same idea already posted about categories... I don't want to have to maintain reasonably equal runtimes between the instances here. I'd rather write my own NUnit runner before I'd do this.

Comment: As far as I know NUnit does not support this without a workaround such as running multiple instances.  If you want I guess you can make a tool that splits the tests into N sets and runs N instances of NUnit automatically where N is the number of processors/cores you have.  That would be the only way to have some sort of automated parallel testing that I can think of with NUnit.

Comment: I added an update discussing the TeamCity continuous integration tool and included a few posts on how to use that tool to solve your automation needs.

Answer (score 3):

Just because PNUnit can do synchronization inside test code doesn't mean that you actually have to use that aspect. As far as I can see there's nothing to prevent you from just spawning a set and ignoring the rest till you need it.

BTW I don't have the time to read all of their source but was curious to check out the Barrier class and it's a very simple lock counter. It just waits till N threads enter and then sends the pulse for all of them to continue running at the same time. That's all there is to it - if you don't touch it, it won't bite you.

Might be a bit counter intuitive for a normal threaded development (locks are normally used to serialize access - 1 by 1) but it is quite a spirited diversion :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can now use [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/) to parallelize your unit tests and you can even configure how many cores should be used by NCrunch and how many should be used by Visual Studio.

plus you get continuous testing as a bonus :)

Comment: NCrunch is great when you're using it within Visual Studio, but it doesn't help when you're trying to parallelize your tests on your build server.

Comment: NCrunch now has a command line tool available that works really nicely on build servers.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a bit of a hack, but you could split the unit tests into a number of [categories](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.5.5). Then, start up a new instance of NUnit for each category.

Edit: It looks like they have added a /process option to the console app. The command-line help states this is the "Process model for tests: Single, Separate, Multiple".  The test runner also appears to have this feature.

Edit 2: Unfortunately, although it does create separate processes for each assembly, the process isolation option (/process from the command line) runs the agents one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Since the project hasn't been mentioned here, I would like to bring up [NUnit.Multicore](http://nunitmulticore.codeplex.com/). I haven't tried the project myself, but it seems to have an interesting approach to the parallel test problem with NUnit.

Answer (score 2):

You can try my small tool [TBox](http://tbox.codeplex.com/) or console parallel [Runner](http://cpntr.codeplex.com/) or even plugin to do distributed calulations, which also can run unit tests on  the set of PCs [SkyNet](https://tbox.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SkyNet&referringTitle=Home)

TBox is created to simplify work with big solutions, which contains many projects. It supports many plugins and one of them provide ability to run NUnit tests in parallel. This plugin does not require any changes to your existing tests.

Also it support:

- Cloning of the folder with unit test (if your tests changes local data),
- Synchronizations of the tests (for example if your tests on
  testfixtureteardown kills all dev servers or chromerunner for qunit )
- x86 mode and Admin privileges to run tests
- Batch run - you can run tests for many assemblies in parallel
- Even for single thread run, works faster than standart nunit runner, if you have much small tests.

Also this tool supports command line tests runner (for parallel run) and you can use it with continuous integration.

Comment: If you are associated with this product, please disclose this. You've posted multiple things pointing to this.

Comment: Sure, TBox - is my own tool.  I have written it in my free time alone. If it is bad practice here to say about free tools, I'll remove this answer, it's no problem :)

Comment: We just want people to be clear about the products they're involved with. If you fully disclose that it's yours, why it would be appropriate to solve the problem posed by the question, and don't promote it too aggressively, your answers should be acceptable here.

Comment: @brad It's open source on Codeplex, not sure why there is an issue here.

Comment: @DanVallejo - Being an open source project is the reason why this wasn't deleted by the community upon posting. We give a little more leeway there, but we do still ask that you disclose your affiliation with the project so that people can understand the context behind your recommendation. Alex did so here, so his answer is perfectly fine as it stands now.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used NUnit 3.0.0 beta-4 to run tests in parallel

- Runs on build server
- Runs Selenium tests
- Has Visual Studio support
- no Resharper support yet

Thanks for [peers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32245011/507699).

Gotchas:

- Parallelizable attribute is not inherited, so it has to be specified on the test class.

Comment: NUnit 3.0 is now out

Answer (score 0):

You can use following PowerShell command (for NUnit3, for NUnit2 change runner name):

```
PS> nunit3-console (ls -r *\bin\Debug\*.Tests.dll | % FullName | sort-object -Unique)
```

Presented command runs all test assemblies in single nunit instance, which allows to leverage engine [built-in parallel test run](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Engine-Parallel-Test-Execution).

**Remarks**

1. Remember to tweak directory search pattern. Given example runs only assemblies ending with `.Tests.dll` and inside `\bin\Debug` directories.
2. Be aware of `Unique` filtering - you may not want to have it.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve level of parallelism ensure to do these two:

1)Nunit Explorer - Settings - Run tests in parallel

2)LevelOfParallelism

This is an assembly-level attribute used to specify the level of parallelism, that is, the maximum number of worker threads executing tests in the assembly.

In Assemblyinfo.cs, set

[assembly:LevelOfParallelism(N)] => here N is number