# How can i cutdown the nunit exceution time?

Tags: c#, nunit

i have to run more than 400 integration test cases to run every day i will take more than 5 hrs to run. how can i cut down the nunit execution time into half? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you using Mock Objects? Stubs? Please give more details.

Comment: i dont have any about it is mock objets or stubs

Comment: @ratty: If the code you are testing uses [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), then inserting mocks or stubs becomes much simpler.  If you wrote the code under test, you might want to look into it.

Comment: How you run tests? MSBuild/Continous Integration Server/Visual Studio/NUnit console?

Comment: im running using nunit console

Answer (score 4):

May be running separate sets of nunit tests across machines can help you.

Comment: Is it any possible to implement threads and reduce time in single PC

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313163/how-can-i-run-nunit-tests-in-parallel

Comment: Unless the processor is multicore, you would not get any advantage of running multiple threads as at a given point of time only one thread would be executing.

Comment: +1; This is the only sure-fire way to make a reduction in execution time, with no knowledge of the code under test.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to refactor your code and tests and introduce mocks.  400 test cases testing classes with mocked dependencies probably shouldn't take 5 hours; maybe 5 minutes.  That's a broad assumption on my part though.

In my experience, when tests takes a long time to run, they're more integration tests than unit tests.  Perhaps this is your intention. If it is not, have a think about how you can better isolate each test case.

If you're only responsible for QA and can't change the code, I'm all out of ideas on actually speeding up NUnit.

Comment: will you provide some examples to implement mocks in my test cases

Comment: If the OP can't change the code, sometimes they can *reconfigure* the code.  For example, if the code is database-agnostic (uses something like `NHibernate` correctly), then they might be able to replace their across-the-wire DB access with an in-memory DB.  Need a lot more details on the app architecture to make any suggestions like this, of course...

Comment: @ratty no-can-do.  mocks are dependent on seams, which are specific to your code under test.