# How to run concurrently NUnit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, parallel-processing

I have a set of integration test written in C# and NUnit and I want to run them in parallel on a build-machine. How do I do that? In a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313163/how-can-i-run-nunit-tests-in-parallel) the accepted solution was:

- Create your own test runner
- Move to MBUnit

There is also a project [NUnit.MultiCore](https://nunitmulticore.codeplex.com/) but it is in Alpha version, which will be scary to use in production... Or run several standard NUnit runners in parallel using the build machine's capabilities, which is a workaround really rather than a durable solution.

Has anything changed so far? I would like to stay with NUnit and I am not too sure how easy it is to build my own test runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version 3, the NUnit framework itself supports parallel test execution. You may choose whether you want parallelism to be at test case level or fixture level.

More details are on [NUnit3 wiki at GitHub](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallel-Test-Execution)

Answer (score 3):

Since NUnit 2.5, [NUnit has shipped with PNUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=pnunit&r=2.5.10) -- a runner that can run NUnit tests in parallel. To my understanding PNUnit will be integrated into the long planned NUnit 3.0.

There's a pretty good overview [how to use it here.](http://www.plasticscm.com/infocenter/technical-articles/pnunit.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What had good expieriences with a tool called ALPACA (see [homepage](http://ppcp.codeplex.com)). This analyzes the code and gives hints for data races and deadlocks. It's not perfect, but was very helpful.