# How to run Selenium webdriver C# tests on multiple browser in parallel

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm currently using Selenium Webdriver with C#. I've successfully executed my test in remote webdriver as well using selenium GRID.

I just configured 5 instances of FF, Chrome and IE in my Grid settings and when I ran my test project on chrome browser, I noticed that just only one instance of chrome is picked. Is this the expected behavior? I was initially in an assumption that the number of tests in a single project will be distributed across multiple browser instances based on the maxinstance and maxsessions. But not sure why it is using just one browser instance for the whole project. Please do let me know if I need to do anything to use more than one browser instance to share/run the test.

Comment: What testing framework are you using? This is also a factor in how many threads are given to the test. NUnit, for instance, cannot support parallelisation.

Comment: Thanks for the response Arran!!.. Unfortunately I am using NUNIT :) Is there any good alternative or workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the standard NUnit runner doesn't support parallelization out of the box.

There are a few alternative unit testing frameworks that you might want to look into that do support parallelized runs like `MbUnit` or `PnUnit`.

One workaround is to split up your test. Some common ways are by DLL, namespace, test name, or category. You could then run your NUnit test in parallel using a MSBuild script.

The final command would look something like this `c:\proj> msbuild /m:8 RunTests.xml`

Check out the answers to this question for more details: [How can I run NUnit tests in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313163/how-can-i-run-nunit-tests-in-parallel)