# .NET testing framework with parallel testcases

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit, xunit

I have unit tests in my `C#` project (`VisualStudio 2015`,`Nunit`). I want to check methods in many different situations with different parameters, to achieve that, i used [TestCases](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData). Each test method works very slow - few seconds, and [TestCases](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData) count in my projects grows.

So now testing takes some minutes. I tried to parallel these tests, by moving each test to separate [TestFixture](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixture-Attribute) - `Nunit` allows to run [TestFixtures](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixture-Attribute) in parallel - [Nunit Documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallelizable-Attribute). It slightly changed situation, but not significantly. I want to parallel tests not on the [TestFixture](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixture-Attribute) level, but on testcases level. I don't know how to do it. I have read documentation for `Nunit`, `Xunit`, `MBUnit` etc. and didn't found the answer.

How can i run my tests in parallel, in such way that testscases will run simultaneously? Which framework to use?

My tests example in pseudocode:

```
public static class GeneralTestCases
{
    public static IEnumerable TestStoresCredentials
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData( ... ).SetName("incorrect password");
            ...
            yield return new TestCaseData( ... ).SetName("incorrect login");
        }
    }
}

[ TestFixture ]
[ Parallelizable ]
internal class GetProducts : BaseTest
{
    [ Test ]
    [ TestCaseSource( typeof( GeneralTestCases ), "TestCases" ) ]
    public void ReceiveProducts( TestCase case )
    {
        // ------------ Arrange
        var service = CreateService( case.User, case.Key, ... );

        // ------------ Act
        var serviceResponse = service.GetProducts(case.SpecialType);

        // ------------ Assert
        ...
        serviceResponse.Message.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
        ...
    }
}


[ TestFixture ]
[ Parallelizable ]
internal class GetOrders : BaseTest
{
    [ Test ]
    [ TestCaseSource( typeof( GeneralTestCases ), "TestCases" ) ]
    public void ReceiveOrders( TestCase case )
    {
        // ------------ Arrange
        var service = CreateService( case.User, case.Key, ... );

        // ------------ Act
        var serviceResponse = service.GetOrders(case.SpecialType);

        // ------------ Assert
        ...
        serviceResponse.Message.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
        ...
    }
}
```

[image]

**Update1**:
I'm thinking about nCrunch, but i don't will it help or not

Comment: maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313163/how-can-i-run-nunit-tests-in-parallel

Answer (score 0):

**xUnit** runs each test class (test collection) in parallel by default.

More info [here](https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html).

Comment: Thanks! If i understand correctly, this approach equals to my current implementation, isn't it? 
Each class can be run in parallel, that means i need to create new once class for each test case. That leads to duplication - 100500 classes with the same members. I need something like horizontal scale. Look at picture in my question.

Comment: I think running 100500 in parallel will not bring you better results. Anyway you should define some limit - it will depend on machine(CPU, memory etc.) and what kind of operations tests are doing (CPU bound or IO bound)

Comment: Off course i'm talking about few hundreds. Even if it fill be 100500 - it will be much faster to create 100500 testcases instead of 100500 tests

Answer (score 0):

After some research i found 2 ways to run tests simultaneously .

1. `Nunit` + `Ncrunch` it allows to run tests in parallel ( test cases
   parallelization supported). But for me this way is not convenient. I
   don't like Ncrunch GUI and it takes time to configura it in correct
   way (long running tests threshold settings, multithreading settings
   etc). Also Ncrunch isn't free.
2. `Nunit` + `Nunit tests runner console`. I choose this way. It allows to
   run tests in parallel, it is free, easy to config, can be runned
   from console. You can configure to run a lot of tests in parallel in 1 conosle window, or run multiple consoles, each one runs 1 test at time

Answer (score 0):

I've done this using NUnit. I have a working project which executes browser tests in method-level.

https://github.com/atmakur/WebTestingFramework