# howto run together multiple instance of selenium browser

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-rc

Is it possible to run together multiple instance of selenium browsers and each one will work for themselve which will increase speed?

i can run one like:

```
ISelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://localhost/");
selenium.Start();
```

but how to open more of them and open page inside each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Selenium Grid](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/):

> (..) Stop waiting hours to get the results of your web acceptance builds! Selenium Grid transparently distribute your tests on multiple machines so that **you can run your tests in parallel**, (..) this will dramatically speeds up in-browser web testing

Getting started it's very easy (http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/get_started.html) and demo site is present too.

Comment: apparently you also have to use PUnit (for NUnit, or a different parallel test runner if you're using a different framework) to get the tests to run in parallel, even when you're using Grid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212863/how-can-i-run-nunitselenium-grid-tests-in-parallel Let me know if you find otherwise!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313163/how-can-i-run-nunit-tests-in-parallel

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

```
ISelenium selenium1 = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome",    "http://localhost/");
selenium1.Start();
selenium1...
ISelenium selenium2 = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome",    "http://localhost/");
selenium2.Start();
selenium2...
```